# Batch file executes wrong logic block

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2022

I have this code and expect `echo GOOD` to execute:

```bash
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('C:\path\to\apache\bin\httpd.exe -t') do set HTTPD_TEST=%%i
IF [/I] %HTTPD_TEST%=="Syntax OK" (
    @echo on
    echo GOOD
) ELSE (
    @echo on
    echo:
    echo RESTART ABORTED. Review errors in config.
)
cmd /k
```

However, it results in this output:

[image]

The output of `C:\path\to\apache\bin\httpd.exe -t` is:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that `%HTTPD_TEST%` does contain the expected value after it's been assigned by outputting it afterwards?

Comment: The square brackets around the `/I` means that `/I` is optional. They should not be included in the command to be executed. Note also that the quotes are included in the comparison, so `%HTTPD_TEST%` should be `"%HTTPD_TEST%"` in all probability.

Comment: The string value of the expanded variable `%HTTPD_TEST%` can never match `Syntax OK` because, at best it would be delimited by the space character, i.e. `Syntax`. You would need to therefore specify, either no delimiters, ```For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^"C:\path\to\apache\bin\httpd.exe^" -t 2^>NUL') Do Set "HTTPD_TEST=%%~G"```, or all tokens, ```For /F "Tokens=*" %%G In ('^"C:\path\to\apache\bin\httpd.exe^" -t 2^>NUL') Do Set "HTTPD_TEST=%%~G"```.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments:

```json
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "HTTPD_TEST="

For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '^"C:\path\to\apache\bin\httpd.exe^" -t 2^>NUL'
) Do Set "HTTPD_TEST=%%~G"

If Not Defined HTTPD_TEST (    
    Echo=
    Echo ERROR problem running httpd.exe    
    GoTo ScriptEnd
)

If /I Not "%HTTPD_TEST%" == "Syntax OK" (
    Echo=
    Echo RESTART ABORTED. Review errors in config.    
    GoTo ScriptEnd
)

Echo=
Echo GOOD

:ScriptEnd
Echo Press any key to exit.
Pause 1>NUL
Exit /B
```

Comment: The code results in "ERROR problem running httpd.exe". Unfortunately, I'm not well-versed enough in batch script to even know where to begin debugging. I'm considering PowerShell as well.

Comment: Well other than changing, ```^"C:\path\to\apache\bin\httpd.exe^"``` to ```C:\path\to\apache\bin\httpd.exe```, _(if your needlessly obfuscated file path doesn't contain spaces or poison characters)_. The first advice would be to change `Off` to `On` on line 1, remove `2^>NUL` on line 7, and look at the output, _(to see what is being returned as `%%G`)_.